# Radio buttons group - setCustomValidity and required option in conflict?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to come up with a form comprised of radio buttons group where a user must select one of the options and if he doesn't there's a custom validity message.

So the logic will be:

1. A user forgets to select an option and the validity message shows up.
2. He goes back and selects any option to go proceed.

The problem is, the way things are it only goes ahead if the selected option is the one with the onclick event as shown below. If it isn't then the message will keep showing up.

I have tried to juggle around with the required, oninvalid and onclick thingies but to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="0" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Click me')" onclick="setCustomValidity('')">Zero<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" class="wrapper">One<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" class="wrapper">Two<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form>
<input type="radio" id="test" name="test" value="0" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Click me')" onclick="clearValidity();" required >Zero<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" onclick="clearValidity()" class="wrapper">One<br>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" onclick="clearValidity()" class="wrapper">Two<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function clearValidity()
{
document.getElementById('test').setCustomValidity('');
}

</script>
```

Comment: You could try adding ` oninput="setCustomValidity('')`. This saves the extra script tag at the bottom.

Comment: watch out for the subtleties in code! all radio buttons should have onclick or oninput attributes that will reset customValidity of the same single button that was set as required

Answer (score 0):

This can be written as a function to make it work on any type of `<input>`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form *[data-custom-validity]').forEach(el => {
    const firstInput = el.querySelector('input:first-of-type')

    // set custom validity if first input is invalid
    firstInput.addEventListener('invalid', () => firstInput.setCustomValidity(el.dataset.customValidity))

    // listen on all inputs for a change
    el.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input =>
        input.addEventListener('change', () => firstInput.setCustomValidity('')))
})
```

```html
<form>
    <div data-custom-validity="Click me.">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I'm leaving it here in case it helps anyone.

```
<div class="genero">

<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Mensaje')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" value="M">Masculino
    
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Mensaje')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" value="F">Femenino

</div>
```